# Form gets submitted despite of invalid inputs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex, forms

I wrote an HTML code in which i'm validating the text field for alphabetical value    `Regex=/^[a-zA-Z]*$/`. Actually for invalid input I want that form should not get submitted.

**Validation Code**

```
function Validate() {
    var fname=$("#fname").val();
    if(!(fname.match(Regex)))   
        alert("Invalid First Name");            
    return false;
}
```

**HTML Code**

```
<input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" onblur="return Validate();"/>
```

What should I do, so that for invalid value form should not get submitted.

Comment: 1) Don't use alert.  Update a validation span in the HTML.  2) Do the validation on the forms `onsubmit` method.  3) Search for `[Javascript]  Validation` here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have to return **false** in onsubmit handler. onblur just handles focus.
Try to change onblur -> onsubmit

Answer (score 0):

Use the onsubmit event of the form element to return true when validation was ok or false if any field did not validate.

Here is a working example. It also demonstrates that you should not rely on client sided validation since nobody stops you from doing the get (or even post) request anyway by just typing in the url. You have been warned about the limitations of client sided validation so here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function Validate() {
    var text = document.getElementById("fname").value;

    // simple validation example
    if (text != "secret") {
        alert("you must enter the right secret string!");
        return false;
    }          

    // everything validated
    return true;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name="myForm" method="get" onsubmit="return Validate();">
     <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```